# Apt update show errors in parrots

Tags: parrot-os

Just installed parrot OS and I am trying to improve my linux skills. So after entering `sudo apt update` I got these errors

```
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/dists/lts/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.parrot.sh'
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/dists/parrot/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.parrot.sh'
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.parrot.sh/direct/parrot/dists/parrot-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.parrot.sh'
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/dists/parrot-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.parrot.sh'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
┌─[user@parrot]─[~]
```

BTW I am doing this in my vmware virtual machine.

Comment: Works fine here (Parrot VM in VMware).  Try:   sudo apt-get --fix-missing update  ....  to get missing updates.   .....   then ...... sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  ....  to install new dependencies   ..... Then try sudo apt-get update again.

Comment: @John, w/o DNS resolv any fix is meaningless

Comment: A VMware VM should provide DNS without any difficulty unless something is screwed up.

Comment: @John Hi John and thanks for your reply. I am still getting the same thing.

Comment: @John, I did install it in my oracle VM and I did not encounter any problems.

Comment: Did you set up your machine as Host Only?  For learning use NAT or Bridged

Comment: I set the network adaptor to bridged. Made the processor size 8gb and 50gb for hard disk.

Comment: Do an IFCONFIG and make sure networking is good. Then run the commands in my first post.

Comment: I just did that command. Funny thing is I can't see my IPv4 address.

Comment: I did a reboot and changed the network adaptor to NAT and its working now. Thanks a lot John for the help.

Comment: I posted an answer for you and trust you will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Parrot OS works fine as a VM in VMware Workstation (or Player). I have it here running and updating.

Use ifconfig to ensure networking is working. <--- Important Step.

Run:

sudo apt-get --fix-missing update .... to get missing updates.

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade .... to install new dependencies

Then run sudo apt-get update again.

Changing from Bridged to NAT would reset your network connection. You may need to do a final restart.

Comment: Thanks for this.